# $\overline{E}\subset \bigcup_{x\in E}\overline{B_x(r_x)} $ if $E\subset \bigcup_{x\in E}\overline{B_x(r_x)} $

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose in a metric space, $E$ is a subset, denote $\overline{B_x(r_x)}$ the closure of open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r_x>0$, suppose $\bigcup_{x\in E}\overline{B_x(r_x)}$ is a cover of E, is it true that

$$\overline{E}\subset \bigcup_{x\in E}\overline{B_x(r_x)} $$

Answer (score 0):

It is not true in general. A counterexample is just the metric space $\mathbb{R}$ with $E = (0,1)$, $r_x = \frac{1}{2} \min \{ x, 1-x\}$ for all $x\in E$.
The union of the $\overline {B_x(r_x)}$ covers $E$, but the points 0 and 1 are not covered.

Comment: so what about $E=[0,1]\cap Q$? where $Q$ is rational number

Comment: In that case $\overline E = [0,1]$ is covered by the union if we choose the $r_x$ for $x\in (0,1)$ in the same way as above. But we could also take an enumeration of $E\cap (0,1) = \{ x_1,x_2,x_3,.. \}$ and let $r_{x_i}' = \frac{r_{x_i}}{2^{i+1}}$ as well as $r_{0}  = r_{1} = \frac{1}{8}$ Then the union of the $\overline {B_{x}(r_x')}$ has measure at most $\frac{3}{4}$ and thus cannot cover $[0,1]$.